# preventing I2C device to be configured as slave twice

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, i2c, slave

I've been using the I2C Slave code by Wolfram Sang to configure a linux (designware) device driver as an I2C slave.
It has been working out, but I consider the following 'bug': I want to catch that the I2C device is not configured as slave device twice. So when somebody tries that, I let i2c_slave_register return a -EBUSY. However, this does not prevent the I2C core from registering the client!

```
i2c-slave-eeprom 0-1063: probe
i2c_designware ffc04000.i2c: adapter already configured as slave
i2c-slave-eeprom 0-1063: i2c_slave_register: adapter returned error -16
i2c-slave-eeprom: probe of 0-1063 failed with error -16
i2c i2c-0: client [slave-24c02] registered with bus id 0-1063
i2c i2c-0: new_device: Instantiated device slave-24c02 at 0x63
```

I found this problem to be cause by the implementation of really_probe and driver_probe_device (dd.c). Both functions return 0 even if an error occurs!
This seems to be a specific choice (see https://lkml.org/lkml/2006/10/17/72 for instance)... but then how should I prevent the core from registering this client? (Or shouldn't I?)